# Partition of Unity

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact and $\{s_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be a countable dense set of $K$. Define, $u_s(x) = \max\{2-\frac{|x-s|}{dist(x,K)},0\}$, 
$\sigma(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j} u_{s_j}(x)$, 
$v_k(x) = \frac{2^{-k}u_{s_k}(x)}{\sigma(x)}$. All these functions are defined for
$x \in K^c$.

The authors (Evans & Gariepy) [Page 14 of this book](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=HZONacVPGlMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=evans%20gariepy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eeivU_TeII29ugTJ0YLgBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=evans%20gariepy&f=false) say that $v_k(x)$ form
partitions of unity on $K^c$. Using the definition of [Partition of Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity), I am unable to show that this is the case, i.e., there exists 
a neighborhood for every $x\in K^c$, where only finitely many functions $v_k$ are non-zero.

For example, let $K$ be the closed unit ball and choose $x$ far enough from $K$ so that there exits no $s$ for which $|x-s| \geq 2dist(x,K)$ and hence infinitely many functions $v_{s_k}$ (all of them) are non zero at this point $x$.

This result is required to prove Lusin's theorem later on in the book.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a partition of unity is usually meant to be locally finite, but there is no law against using the term in other ways. The authors never defined *partition of unity* in the book. It seems that they use it for any collection of nonnegative functions that add  up to $1$.

The authors were aware of the fact that the sum is not locally finite, because they refer to the Weierstrass M-test to argue that $\bar f$ is continuous. For a locally finite partition of unity, that would not be needed.